# Functions for pressing and releasing a button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am doing a JavaScript project for a class and cannot seem to get two of the functions to work.  They are `swapFE` and `swapEF`.  Essentially what I am trying to do is that when the user clicks down on the mouse button the French phrase swaps to English.  When the mouse button is released it is supposed to swap back to French.  Below is what I have for the entire project, including HTML code.  If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on JavaScript, 2nd Edition
   Tutorial 7
   Case Problem 1

   French Phrases
   Author:  Chris Carter        
   Date:  10/21/2013           

   Filename:         french5.htm
   Supporting files: engfr.js, french.js, styles.css

-->
   <title>French Phrases Week 5</title>
   <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src ="engfr.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src ="french5.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>


</head>

<body>
   <div id = "page">
      <div id="head">
         <div id = "rightHead">
            <b>Prof. Eve Granger</b><br />
            Office: 810 Linton Hall<br />
            Hours: TR: 3:00-4:30
         </div>
         <div id = "leftHead">
            <b>French 101</b><br />
            MWF: 9:00-9:50<br />
            Rm. 402 Linton Hall
         </div>
      </div>

      <ul id="links">
         <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Phrases</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Week 1 Phrases</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Week 2 Phrases</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Week 3 Phrases</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Week 4 Phrases</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Week 5 Phrases</a></li>
         <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Quizzes</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Chapter 1 Quiz</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Chapter 2 Quiz</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Chapter 3 Quiz</a></li>
         <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Dept. of French</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">French 101</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">French 135</a></li>  
         <li><a href="#">French 155</a></li>  
         <li><a href="#">French 201</a></li>  
         <li><a href="#">French 301</a></li>   
         <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Denise Abbot</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Viola Devreaux</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Eve Granger</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Cynthia Trudeau</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Gary Vironque</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id = "doc">
         <h1>Week 5 Phrases</h1>
         <h2>Press down your mouse button on each phrase to translate</h2>

      </div>
      <address>
         French-English Translation Page
      </address>
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the JavaScript code that has the Arrays for both English and French:

```
  /*
   New Perspectives on JavaScript, 2nd Edition
   Tutorial 7
   Case Problem 1

   Filename: french5.js


   Variable List:
   french
      Contains an array of 10 english phrases

   english
      Contains an array of 10 French translations
    */

    var english=new Array();
    english[0]="This hotel isn't far from the Eiffel Tower.";
    english[1]="What time does the train arrive?";
    english[2]="We have been waiting for the bus for one half-hour.";
    english[3]="This meal is delicious";
    english[4]="What day is she going to arrive?";
    english[5]="We have eleven minutes before the train leaves!";
    english[6]="Living in a foreign country is a good experience.";
    english[7]="Excuse me! I'm late!";
    english[8]="Is this taxi free?";
    english[9]="Be careful when you go down the steps.";

    var french=new Array();
    french[0]="Cet h&#244;tel n'est pas loin de la Tour Eiffel.";
    french[1]="A quelle heure arrive le train?";
    french[2]="Nous attendons l'autobus depuis une demi-heure.";
    french[3]="Ce repas est d&#233;licieux";
    french[4]="Quel jour va-t-elle arriver?";
    french[5]="Nous avons onze minutes avant le d&#233;part du train!";
    french[6]="Habiter dans un pays &#233;tranger est une bonne exp&#233;rience.";
    french[7]="Excusez-moi! Je suis en retard!";
    french[8]="Est-ce que ce taxi est libre?";
    french[9]="Faites attention quand vous descendez l'escalier.";
```

And this is the code that I am currently working on:

```
/*
   New Perspectives on JavaScript, 2nd Edition
   Tutorial 7
   Case Problem 1

   Author: Chris Carter
   Date:   10/21/2013  

   Filename: engfr.js


   Function List:

   addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap)
      Adds an event hander to object where evName is the name of the event,
      fnName is the function assigned to the event, and cap indicates whether
      event handler occurs during the capture phase (true) or bubbling
      phase (false)

   setUp()
      Insert the current week's french phrases into document and set up
      event handlers for the phrases.

   swapFE(phrase, pnum)
      Changes a French phrase to the English version of that phrase.

   swapEF(phrase, pnum)
      Changes an English phrase ot the Frech version of that phrase.

*/

function addEvent(object, evName, fnName, cap) {
   if (object.attachEvent)
       object.attachEvent("on" + evName, fnName);
   else if (object.addEventListener)
       object.addEventListener(evName, fnName, cap);
}

addEvent (window, "load", setUp, false);

function setUp() {
    var transDoc = document.getElementById("doc");
    var olElem = document.createElement("ol");
    for (var i = 0; i < french.length; i++) {
        var newLI = document.createElement("li");
        newLI.innerHTML = french[i];
        newLI.id = i + "phrase";
        newLI.style.cursor = "pointer";
        addEvent(newLI, "onmousedown", swapFE, false);
        addEvent(newLI, "onmouseup", swapEF, false);
        olElem.appendChild(newLI);
    }
    transDoc.appendChild(olElem);
}

function swapFE(phrase, pNum) {
    var phrase = e.target || event.srcElement;
    var pNum = 0;
    if (phrase.nodeType == "#text") {
        phrase = phrase.parent.Node
    }
        pNum = parseInt(phrase.id);
        phrase.innerHTML = english[pNum];
        phrase.style.fontStyle = "italic";
        phrase.style.color = "rgb(155, 102, 102)";
    }
}

function swapEF(phrase, pNum) {
    var phrase = e.target || event.srcElement;
    var = 0;
    if (phrase.nodeType == "#text") {
        phrase = phrase.parentNode
    }
        pNum = parseInt(phrase.id);
        phrase.innerHTML = french[pNum];
        phrase.style.fontStyle = "normal";
        phrase.style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function addEvent already adds the "on" to "onMouseDown" and "onMouseUp" removing the on would fix your problem and allow you to continue debugging.